# How to solve the "undefined reference to 'ntohl'" compile error in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

How to solve the compile error?

```
 error: undefined reference to 'ntohl' 
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use the android-ndk-r10d.

Comment: Have you included `<sys/endian.h>` ?

Comment: Yes. It works after include the `<sys/endian.h>`. Please post it as an answer. I will accept. Thanks. @Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building with the Android NDK, `ntohl` and the other functions for converting between network and host byte order are `#defines` present in the header `<sys/endian.h>`. So including that header should fix your compilation error.